# Spring mvcresource configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources, http-status-code-404

I have a structure as such:

```
UsherSchedule/war
- src
  - main
    - webapp 
      - resources
        - js
        - css
      - WEB-INF
         - views
           - jsp
             - index.jsp
         - ushering-config.xml
         - web.xml
```

My ushering-config.xml has a line for resouces:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/*" />
```

My index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jsrender.js" />" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: right;">
                <select id="cboSchedule">
                    <option value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried referencing jsrender.js using normal methods of just   as well as

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your WEB-INF directory inside src/main/webapp directory and then change your configuration like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
```

Comment: Sorry It was a lapse of noticing the tabs being off in that diagram.  Edited to display properly...I'll try the change in mvc:resources though

Comment: That worked like a charm and I'll mark it up as an answer but how might I change it so I don't have to use /resources/js for my URLs but just /js?  I tried removing resources from both mapping and location one at a time to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js/" /> should work